# Mathematics Debt problem

Tags: algorithms

Imagine that there is a group of three friends: $A$, $B$ and $С$. $A$ owes $B\,$ $20$ rubles and $B$ owes $C\,$ $20$ rubles. The total sum of the debts is $40$ rubles. We can see that the debts are not organized in a very optimal manner. Let's rearrange them like that: assume that $A$ owes $C\,$ $20$ rubles and $B$ doesn't owe anything to anybody. The debts still mean the same but the total sum of the debts now equals $20$ rubles.

Our task is a generalisation of a described example. Imagine that we have $n$ people and I know the debts between the people. I need to optimize the given debts without changing their meaning. In other words, finally for each person the difference between the total money he should give and the total money he should take must be the same.Ineed to Print the minimum sum of all debts in the optimal rearrangement of the debts.

It is guaranteed if $x$ owe money to $y$ then $y$ can't owe it to $x$.

**Example.**

Let we have $n=5$ people and $m=3$ debts. Next $m$ lines describe 
$(a_i, b_i, d_i)$ meaning person $a_i$ owes person $b_i\,$ $d_i$ rubles.

$$(1, 2, 10)$$

$$(2, 3, 1)$$

$$(2, 4, 1)$$

Here, the answer would be $10$.

As we can assume that person number $1$ owes $8$ rubles to person number $2$, $1$ ruble to person number $3$ and $1$ ruble to person number $4$. He doesn't owe anybody else anything. In the end, the total debt equals $10$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint:  think about each person's net - what they are owed minus what they owe.

Comment: Can u please explain a bit..

Comment: @user3001932:  Look at your examples.  Make a list of the people, the final result, and compare that with my description.

Comment: ..I am getting it. But could u please tell a short algorithm or so to do the same?

Comment: If you are getting it, the algorithm is easy to see.  Note that you are not asked to say who owes how much to whom, just the total of the optimized amounts.

Comment: I had thought to manage two arrays one of owing and one that owes which here would be [10 2 0 0 0] and [0 10 1 1 0].Now we can get net of  each.After that i am not getting it

Comment: So what the net of each person at the start?

Comment: I dont find a way to find it out..:(

Comment: So 2 is due 10 from 1 and owes 1 to 3 and 1 to 4.  How many rubles will he have at the end?